# Sharepoint 2007 document library list template

Tags: library, document

I inherited a sharepoint site that includes a template being applided to all the document libraries within the site. When a user creates a new document library, it automatically gets populated from the template with a set of folders and word/excel documents within each of the folders. I am trying to find out how to change one of the excel document the template adds to a folder. I opened the list template stp file from the gallery and looked at its manifest.xml file. Here is an example of one of the folder and file elements:

```
<Files>
<Folder Name="Build Book">
<MetaInfo><MetaKey Name="vti_isexecutable" Value="BR|false" /><MetaKey Name="vti_listenableminorversions" Value="BR|false" /><MetaKey Name="vti_listenablemoderation" Value="BR|false" /><MetaKey Name="vti_level" Value="IR|1" /><MetaKey Name="vti_rtag" Value="SW|rt:4B811DE9-9E55-419C-B0F1-F8FBD53ABBC8@00000000000" /><MetaKey Name="vti_etag" Value="SW|&quot;{4B811DE9-9E55-419C-B0F1-F8FBD53ABBC8},0&quot;" /><MetaKey Name="vti_isbrowsable" Value="BR|true" /><MetaKey Name="vti_isscriptable" Value="BR|false" /><MetaKey Name="vti_hassubdirs" Value="BR|false" /><MetaKey Name="vti_listbasetype" Value="IR|1" /><MetaKey Name="vti_timecreated" Value="TR|13 Feb 2012 16:01:19 -0000" /><MetaKey Name="vti_docstoretype" Value="IR|1" /><MetaKey Name="vti_listservertemplate" Value="IR|101" /><MetaKey Name="vti_listname" Value="SR|{34326968-EF95-4D30-9BAF-A84A62FFC423}" /><MetaKey Name="vti_listenableversioning" Value="BR|true" /><MetaKey Name="vti_candeleteversion" Value="BR|true" /><MetaKey Name="vti_dirlateststamp" Value="TW|13 Feb 2012 15:59:05 -0000" /><MetaKey Name="vti_timelastmodified" Value="TR|13 Feb 2012 16:01:19 -0000" /><MetaKey Name="vti_listrequirecheckout" Value="BR|false" /><MetaKey Name="vti_replid" Value="SR|rid:{4B811DE9-9E55-419C-B0F1-F8FBD53ABBC8}" /></MetaInfo>
<File Name="BuildBook.xlsx" Src="00000000.000">
<MetaInfo><MetaKey Name="Subject" Value="EW|" /><MetaKey Name="vti_rtag" Value="SW|rt:BA1DACF7-BAB4-40EB-A48D-B00895114D50@00000000001" /><MetaKey Name="vti_etag" Value="SW|&quot;{BA1DACF7-BAB4-40EB-A48D-B00895114D50},1&quot;" /><MetaKey Name="Keywords" Value="EW|" /><MetaKey Name="_Status" Value="EW|" /><MetaKey Name="vti_parserversion" Value="SR|12.0.0.6421" /><MetaKey Name="vti_modifiedby" Value="SR|WGL\msticht" /><MetaKey Name="vti_filesize" Value="IR|20182" /><MetaKey Name="vti_timecreated" Value="TR|12 Jan 2011 19:32:13 -0000" /><MetaKey Name="vti_docstoretype" Value="IR|0" /><MetaKey Name="vti_docstoreversion" Value="IR|1" /><MetaKey Name="vti_title" Value="SW|Build Book" /><MetaKey Name="_Author" Value="SW|Sticht, Michael" /><MetaKey Name="_Category" Value="EW|" /><MetaKey Name="ContentType" Value="LW|Document" /><MetaKey Name="ContentTypeId" Value="SW|0x01010002B8191061343F4C81154FFC6F58E9F4" /><MetaKey Name="vti_timelastmodified" Value="TR|12 Jan 2011 19:32:13 -0000" /><MetaKey Name="vti_candeleteversion" Value="BR|true" /><MetaKey Name="vti_canmaybeedit" Value="BX|true" /><MetaKey Name="_Comments" Value="EW|" /><MetaKey Name="vti_author" Value="SR|WGL\msticht" /><MetaKey Name="vti_replid" Value="SR|rid:{BA1DACF7-BAB4-40EB-A48D-B00895114D50}" /><MetaKey Name="vti_sourcecontrolversion" Value="SR|V1.0" /><MetaKey Name="vti_sourcecontrolcookie" Value="SR|fp_internal" /><MetaKey Name="vti_level" Value="IR|1" /></MetaInfo>
</File>
```

The folder name is Build Book and the excel document being created in the folder is BuildBook.xlsx. Problem is I don't know where the hell the BuildBook.xlsx template file is located so I can switch it out with the new version of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be to regenerate the STP file. Probably the stp is create by saving a site as template or document library as a template from the UI.

One way to update is to roll out a new blank document library based on the .stp template. Update the excel template file and then recreate the .stp-file.

Other option: (UNTESTED, NOT CHECKED) The xml-file mentions that the excel file is stored in a file called 000000.000 inside the stp. Maybe just replacing that file by the new excel template file and reuploading the template might work.

Comment: Ahhh. The src attribute is the source for the file. I did see these .000 files in the stp file after I turned it into a cab file. I guess I will have to recreate. Thanks!